# Might would? if i could?

Tags: word-usage

How accurate is it to say I might would, if I could? Just reading on the intricacies of can and may and it got me curious.

Comment: I would, if I could; but I can't, so I won't.

Comment: Feasibly there could be some dialectal pocked where *I might would* is a valid construction, but I rather doubt it. I think this is General Reference - the answer being it's ***not at all accurate*** (i.e. - it's totally ungrammatical).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: not so fast. Modal stacking is the name, and guess [which country](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/3214/300) likes playing weird games virtually unknown outside of it.

Comment: @Reg: I guess I might shouldn't have been so hasty (or ***maybe** I shouldn't have*, as the rest of us say). In my defence though, even though I'm not aware of having come across it before (which is presumably why it sounds so weird to me), I could almost imagine the "logic" of such construction. So I claim half a brownie point for having the presence of mind to say *feasibly ... dialectal* (despite the fact that I didn't believe it *at all* at time of writing! :)