# Is "That might even could happen" considered incorrect?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, multiple-modals

Would you help me out with examining this sentence? Is "That might even could happen"  considered incorrect?

Comment: Related [Is “might could” a correct construct](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/is-might-could-a-correct-construct)

Comment: There is a trend among people who study English, currently, to shy away from sharp categorization of "correct" and "not correct".  The contemporary rule of thing is: if your interlocutor understood what you meant, it was "correct" (because, after you spoke,  specifically what you wanted to communicate is n his head). With that said, let me buck the descriptivist trend here (it's *so mainstream*; I'm into this thing called prescriptivism now, though you probably haven't heard of it): **no**, "*that even might could happen*" is **not correct**. Don't use it.

Comment: Hello! I appreciate your quick reply! I have read through the related topic, very comprehensive. Wouldn't "even" soften the antagonism? "Might even" and "could happen" are valid connections, aren't they? Thank you

Comment: @Dan: In general, I'm not big on the correct/incorrect distinction either. But as the top-rated answer on the original says of this usage, it's [*restricted to certain dialects of US English. In Standard English, it is not grammatical. This construction is also often stigmatized*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/3214/2637). My position on this one would be *"Don't feel ashamed or obliged to change if you were brought up using it, but don't **deliberately** adopt it if it's not part of your natural usage"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"may/might" is a modal verb and after modal verbs only a bare infinitive can follow as in: "May/might I help you?" or a bare infinitive perfect as in: He may/might have done it". But a structure such as "may/might + could ( a finite verb form)" is not possible.

I assume you wanted to say "That might have happened".

Comment: Thank you. Sort of that is what I meant. Though, it felt as if it hadn't quite do justice to my emotional state. I wished to express strong skepticism.